# Generalizing reflection principle to arbitrary domains

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I know that by using Morera's theorem, the symmetry principle holds for holomorphic functions. However, the problem above has the intersection of two domains as some curve. So, how do I formulate a clean argument showing that $f$ is holomorphic in the whole region shown there? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: The text in that image is quite small and difficult to read. I suggest that you typeset the statement in LaTeX/MathJAX. And please tell us where the statement comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that this is a local problem and we need to prove the result only in the neighborhood of $w \in \Gamma$ which is not an endpoint, as obviously $F$ is analytic on $D_1 \cup D_2$

Now, since $\Gamma$ is simple there is a small arc $\alpha$ of it containing $w$ s.t. its endpoints $A,B$ can be joined by small, close-by simple arcs $\alpha_{1,2}$ contained in $D_{1,2}$, s.t $\beta_{1,2}=\alpha \cup \alpha_{1,2}$ (simple closed curves) bound simply connected domains $G_{1,2} \subset D_{1,2}$. Let $\beta=\alpha_1 \cup \alpha_2$; notice also that one of $\beta_{1,2}$ goes counterclockwise and one clockwise when we go first on $\alpha$ and then on $\alpha_{1,2}$

Consider $F_{1,2}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\beta_{1,2}}\frac{F(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$, defined say for $z \in G_1 \cup G_2$.

$F$ is continuos and equal to $f_{1,2}$ in $\bar{G_1} \cup \bar{G_2}$ as $f_1=f_2$ on $\alpha$, so by Cauchy (remembering that $G_{1,2}$ are simply connected) we get $F_1(z)=f_1(z)=F(z)$ in $G_1$ and $F_1(z)=0$ in $G_2$ and the analogous relation for $F_2$ reversing the roles of $G_1, G_2$, so in particular $F(z)=F_1(z)+F_2(z), z \in G_1 \cup G_2$

Now adding the integrals (which are both counterclockwise by standard definition), we notice that $\alpha$ is traversed opposite in one vs the other (see comment above), so its contribution cancels out and $F(z)=F_1(z)+F_2(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\beta}\frac{F(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$ in $G_1 \cup G_2$. But $G_1 \cup G_2 \cup$ interior $\alpha$ is the inside of the domain bounded by the Jordan curve $\beta$, so (by Cauchy again) the integral above is analytic throughout the full domain bounded by $\beta$, hence on (the interior of) $\alpha$, hence at $w$ and it obviously equals $F(z)$ there by continuity. Done!

Comment: $F$ is merely continuous. How can you conclude that the integral is analytic? My knowledge says that $F$ itself must be analytic to claim that the integral is anayltic.

Comment: Continuos on the boundary enough to imply the cauchy integral is analytic inside, because you can expand the $\frac{1}{\zeta -z_0}$ in powers of $(z-z_0)$ for $z$ in a disc near $z_0$ st the radius is smaller than the distance from $z$ to the boundary (usual trick doing fractions etc

Comment: You mean that analyticity inside and continuity on the boundary are sufficient to ensure that the integral on the boundary is analytic for points $z$ inside?

Comment: Continuity on the boundary is enough to imply cauchy integral is analytic inside on simply connected domains with Jordan boundary ( just convince yourself by doing the fraction trick)

Comment: If you know the function you integrate on the boundary comes from an analytic function inside, then the cauchy integral of the boundary is equal to the original function inside